# Get value of #text from JSON response

Tags: jquery, json

I am trying to fetch information about an artist and I am using Last Fm API to do that. Following is the response that I am getting from it.

```
image: [
{
    #text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/81638003.png",
    size: "small"
},
{
    #text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/81638003.png",
    size: "medium"
},
{
    #text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/81638003.png",
    size: "large"
},
{
    #text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/81638003.png",
    size: "extralarge"
},
{
    #text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/81638003/Imagine+Dragons.png",
    size: "mega"
}
],
```

I want to get the URL of a particular Image and I am using following code to get it.

```
$(".artistInfo").append(data.artist.image[3]['#text']);
```

But It is not working. Can somebody please help me to get the link of an image.

I would be very thankful to you guys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't see the `data.artist` variable, where you get it.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot use '#' in the starting while defining a property name in the Object. You need to remove it. Then you can access it directly

JS:

```
var data={artist:{}}
data.artist.image=[
{
    text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/34/81638003.png",
    size: "small"
},
{
    text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/64/81638003.png",
    size: "medium"
},
{
    text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/126/81638003.png",
    size: "large"
},
{
    text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/252/81638003.png",
    size: "extralarge"
},
{
    text: "http://userserve-ak.last.fm/serve/_/81638003/Imagine+Dragons.png",
    size: "mega"
}
]

alert(data.artist.image[3].text);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k6G4Z/2/